# Can't read value from Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I've implmented Azure Key Vault in my Azure Functions app following this article:
https://medium.com/statuscode/getting-key-vault-secrets-in-azure-functions-37620fd20a0b

As described in the article, I'm using Managed Service Identity (MSI) but looks like I'm unable to read values from Key Vault. The following is the line that is supposed to read the value.

```
var myValue = (await kvClient.GetSecretAsync(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("documentDbkey"))).Value;
```

This is what my entries look like on Azure KeyVault:
[image]

Am I supposed to use the `key` for my entry i.e. `documentDb` or the version Id which is the one that starts with `bf2550f4e`?

Here's error:

> Exception while executing function: IngridNotificationsFunction
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception
>   while executing function: IngridNotificationsFunction --->
>   System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   secretIdentifier    at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretAsync(??)
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at async Ingrid.Notifications.IngridNotifications.Initialize() at
>   C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\Ingrid.Notifications\Ingrid.Notifications\IngridNotifications.cs
>   : 83    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   async Ingrid.Notifications.IngridNotifications.Run(String myQueueItem)
>   at C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\Ingrid.Notifications\Ingrid.Notifications\IngridNotifications.cs
>   : 38    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnType](TReflected
>   instance,Object[] arguments) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\VoidTaskMethodInvoker.cs
>   : 20    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object
>   instance,Object[] arguments) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs
>   : 63    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker
>   invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource
>   timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource
>   functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan
>   timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hos…

What could be the reason why I'm unable to read values from my Azure KeyVault?

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null

---

According to the exception, it indicates that `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("documentDbkey")` is null.

> What could be the reason why I'm unable to read values from my Azure KeyVault?

If we want to use **Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("documentDbkey")** we need to config the azure function app setting to add the key documentDbkey with value `https://{yourkeyvalue}.vault.azure.net/Secrets/{yourSecretName}` in your case.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

You could use the following code directly to get the secret.

```
kvClient.GetSecretAsync("https://{yourkeyvalue}.vault.azure.net/Secrets/{yourSecretName}")​.Value
```

[image]

In the [article](https://medium.com/statuscode/getting-key-vault-secrets-in-azure-functions-37620fd20a0b) also mentioned that he use the application setting for storing the key vault secret id.

> You’ll notice I am using an **environment variable (application setting)** in this case for the key vault secret ID, but that itself is not a secret — just a location of where the secret is stored

Comment: I'm trying to read these values from Azure Key Vault, not app settings. The article that I'm following has the following code that is used to read values from Azure Key Vault and looks like `GetEnvironmentVariable()` is being used within the context of the Azure Key Vault client. Here's the code: `kvClient.GetSecretAsync(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EventHubSecretId"))).Value;`

Comment: I have updated the answer.  In you mentioned blog that the author use  the environment variable (application setting) for storing the secret id. You also could use the secret id directly.  `kvClient.GetSecretAsync("https://{yourkeyvalue}.vault.azure.net/Secrets/{yourSecretName}")​.Value`